# My class object ID is not being maintained

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following point class:

```
class Point:
    """Two-Dimensional Point(x, y)"""
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        # Initialize the Point instance
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __iter__(self):
         yield self.x
         yield self.y

    def __iadd__(self, other):
         self.x = self.x + other.x
         self.y = self.y + other.y
         return Point(self.x, self.y)
 #       return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __add__(self, other):
         return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        mulx = self.x * other
        muly = self.y * other
        return Point(mulx, muly)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        mulx = self.x * other
        muly = self.y * other
        return Point(mulx, muly)

    @classmethod
    def from_tuple(cls, tup):
        x, y = tup
        return cls(x, y)

    def loc_from_tuple(self, tup):
  #       self.x=t[0]
  #       self.y=t[1]
        self.x, self.y = tup

    @property
    def magnitude(self):
        # """Return the magnitude of vector from (0,0) to self."""
        return math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)

    def distance(self, self2):
         return math.sqrt((self2.x - self.x) ** 2 + (self2.y - self.y) ** 2)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Point at ({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(x={},y={})".format(self.x, self.y)
```

During addition, I want the ID of a point before addition to be the same as after addition as follows:

```
point1 = Point(2, 3)
point2 = Point(4, 5)
id1 = id(point1)
point1 += point2
print(point1)
    Point(x=6, y=8)
print(id1 == id(point1))
    True
print(point2)
    Point(x=4, y=5)
```

When I run this code however, I get everything correct except the ID returns false. Is there a flaw in my code which is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `__iadd__` implementation. You should return `self` instead of creating new object.

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    self.x = self.x + other.x
    self.y = self.y + other.y
    return self
```